# Do I need to repair this PVC drain pipe elbow?

Tags: plumbing, pipe

I was trying to mount a shelf and while drilling holes for the screws, felt some resistance against the drill. Tried to push the drill a bit further, but stopped as I was not sure what the resistance was. Removed some more drywall to see that I had scraped a 45 degree elbow joint on the PVC drain pipe. The scrape looks like its right at the end of the elbow (bell-end?). This looks like a drain pipe draining from the 2nd floor. There is no leak. Can I just put some epoxy on this or am I going to need to do a bigger repair?

[image: Scraped pipe]
[image: Size of hole for reference]
[image: Photo without flash]

Comment: New pipe/fittings come from the store with worse dings than that. Looks like ABS DWV pipe, not PVC. The solvent cement used to "glue" pipe/fittings together is a better patcher than epoxy.

Comment: Drain pipes aren't under pressure. It just looks dinged, if it's not leaking I wouldn't sweat it.

Comment: Thank you, these comments make me less anxious. Never tried working with plumbing, so this had me worried. I want to patch it just to be extra careful.

Comment: @kreemoweet isn't ABS usually black not grey/white? I've not purchased/used/seen in the field ABS pipe, so I'm not 100% certain...

Comment: I had pictures from before the drywall went up. The pipe is labelled as "Cellular Core PVC pipe". The pipe itself is white, but the elbow is a slightly different shade of white. Maybe the flash from the phone makes it look darker. Adding a photo without the flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably fine as it is.

The stuff to use to fix this is a PVC solvent cement that contains a lot of filler, eg: "Marley MCS® Solvent Cement"
or you could mix in some ground PVC to regular PVC pipe
cement to make a paste.

To ensure a good weld, prime the surface first with PVC pipe primer.

There's going to be lots of yucky volatile chemicals so crank up the ventilation.